# How to update python 2.7 to 3.5 on a freeNAS os

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7, python-3.x, freebsd

I have tried pip, easy_install, pkg update, pkg install, and building from source and all have failed. All I want to do is be able to have python 3.5 run and I am getting desperate at this point.

Comment: Are you getting some sort of error?

Answer (score 1):

Is your freeNAS server the kind that is built on Debian?

If so you can try:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install python3.5
```

See:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/682869/how-do-i-install-newer-python-versions-using-apt-get

If the above doesn't work, try posting here the output from these commands:

```
uname -a
cat /etc/issue
cat /proc/version
```

Comment: FreeBSD cascade.toyon.corp 10.3-STABLE FreeBSD 10.3-STABLE #0 455d13d(9.10-STABLE): Sun Jun 26 22:47:03 PDT 2016     root@build.ixsystems.com:/tank/home/nightlies/build-freenas9/_BE/objs/tank/home/nightlies/build-freenas9/_BE/trueos/sys/FreeNAS.amd64  amd64

Comment: cat: /etc/issue: No such file or directory

Comment: cat: /proc/version: No such file or directory

Comment: the outputs respectively

Comment: apparently the freeBSD equivalent of apt-get is pkg when i run the command `sudo pkg install python3-3_3` it throws this:  `pkg: archive_read_open_filename(//usr/ports/packages/All/python34-3.4.4_3.txz): Failed to open '//usr/ports/packages/All/python34-3.4.4_3.txz'`